# How to delete all files, excluding those in a directory?

Tags: linux, find

I want to delete all .pyc and .pyo files recursively but exclude a certain directory.  I just ran into some limitation where find cannot delete when ignoring.  I tried piping the result to `xargs rm` but that fails, too.

```
find . -not \( -path somedir -prune \) -name '*.py[co]' -exec rm '{}' \;
```

with error:

```
find: The -delete action atomatically turns on -depth, but -prune does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.
```

This also fails:

```
find . -type f -not -path 'somdir/*' -name '*.py[co]' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Versions:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- find version 4.4.2

Comment: whoops, no.  that was my comment from the run.  removed, thanks.

Comment: Strange error. There is no `-delete` in your `find` invocation…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I needed to explicitly put the prefix of `.` in front of the directory.  I'm not sure I completely understand why, but for anyone else in this situation:

Fails:

```
find . -type f -not -path 'somdir/*' -name '*.py[co]' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Works:

```
find . -type f -not -path './somdir/*' -name '*.py[co]' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing how `-not` and `-prune` interact.  The usual thing is "find this and prune it, or this and prune it, or this and actually do something with it."

```
find . -path somedir -prune -o -name '*.py[co]' -delete
```

I replaced `-exec ...` with `-delete` which runs a built-in delete action with no external processes.  If you want to `-exec` something else at some point, perhaps use `-exec command {} +` instead of `-exec command {} \;` (and notice how the single quotes around `{}` aren't really useful; the shell will process and remove them before `find` runs anyway).

Comment: No, you're right, the error message doesn't look like it comes from `find` at all.

Comment: that fails with error: `find: The -delete action atomatically turns on -depth, but -prune does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.
`

Comment: both versions produce the same result, deleting files in `somedir` when i don't want to touch that dir.

Comment: Can you reveal what exactly `somedir` corresponds to and how you identify it in the `find` command line?  For example, `find . -path .git -prune -o -ls` prints stuff in `./.git/` but `find . -path ./.git -prune -o -ls` works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If "somedir" are not so many, you can remove the write permission temporarily and just `-name '*.py[co]' -delete` all of them.

Remember add the write permission back to "somedir".

Br,

Answer (score 0):

Do the filtering with `awk`, and use `xargs` to run the command?

```
find . -type f -name '*.py[co]' -print0 \
    | awk -vRS='\0' '!/^.\/somedir\//' \
    | xargs -0 rm
```

`awk` parameters:

- `-vRS='\0'` sets RS (Record Separator) to nul (`\0`) instead of the default (`\n`)
- `!` negates the regex
- `^./somedir/` any record beginning with `./somedir/`

  - don't forget to escape the regex / path slashes - raw regex becomes: `^.\/somedir\/`